# Passing multiple Key Values using Postman Tool for API

Tags: postman

It is a basic question from a newbie. I am testing an API using Postman Tool. I am new to using Postman tool. Here are the details:

```
"custretryatmpt": 1,   
 "isrefno":true,
"msisdnlist":[{"phoneno":"9XXXXXXXXXX","agentno":"8XXXXXXXXX"}]
```

I know how to enter the Keys & value for custretryatmpt and isrefno. How to enter Key & Value for

```
"msisdnlist":[{"phoneno":"9XXXXXXXXXX","agentno":"8XXXXXXXXX"}]
```

Requesting help...

Comment: Is It a POST request?

Comment: Yes, it is POST

Answer (score 1):

> click body tab and select round row button
> select Json right cornar.
> paste json below
> send

```
{
        "custretryatmpt": 1,
        "isrefno": true,
        "msisdnlist": [
            {
                "phoneno": "9XXXXXXXXXX",
                "agentno": "8XXXXXXXXX"
            }
        ]
    }
```

> Select your request method type (POST)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's a lot easier to explain it with an image. Also the link https://community.postman.com/t/sending-an-array-as-form-data/4606 from the post can be helpful.

Comment: is it msisdnlist[0]phoneno and msisdnlist[1]agentno ...The Index ???

Comment: If I am not misunderstanding, my answer is yes. And this https://medium.com/@darilldrems/how-to-send-arrays-with-get-or-post-request-in-postman-f87ca70b154e maybe helpful, too.

Comment: In the image it is msisdnlist[0]phoneno  and msisdnlist[0]agentno

Comment: Well, my fault. It's  msisdnlist[0][phoneno] and msisdnlist[0][agentno] you just mentioned